# How to change button text based on user text input JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, button, jquery-autocomplete

I have a button and a JQuery autocomplete.  I want to make it so that it works like this:

```
if(input=='') {
    button.text = "hello";
}
else {
    button.text = "world";
}
```

I dont know how to incorporate this in my script so that the button changes in real time depending on the state of the autocomplete input.

Any thoughts would be great.  Thanks

Comment: ...what is your question, what is your problem?

Comment: Please provide [`jsfiddle example`](http://jsfiddle.net) of what you currently have.

Comment: you would use button.text("hello"), of course, if button is your correctly chosen jQuery elmenent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just bind an event handler to the text field's `keyup` event like this:

```
$('#inputWrapper').on('keyup', '#tags', function() {
    if($(this).val() == '') {
        $('button.addButton').text('Hello');
    } else {
        $('button.addButton').text('World');
    }
});
```

Here's an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r4emt/8/).

Comment: I figured it out :) Thanks for the help.

Comment: Actually, I have a question.  How come after you add something and then try and replace it with a different item, the button still says "world" instead of "hello".  The input box is empty so it the button should say "hello" but doesn't.  If you click in the box and hit delete or back arrow, it then changes to "hello" even though there was nothing to delete or go to the left of.  Why is this and how do I make it so it says "hello" without me having to do that?  Thanks